# USB EHCI, compatibility with low speed and full speed devices

Tags: usb, avr

Can **EHCI** be used with **USB 2.0 low speed and full speed devices**?

Basically the datasheet of ATXMega256 says that its USB 2.0 port supports full and low speed modes. I want to know if I can connect with a USB port being controlled by EHCI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all USB 2.0 hosts support both low and full speed. The EHCI interface specification.

> The EHCI driver provided high-speed functions for USB ports on the motherboard or on the NEC based card. In more recent hardware, all ports are routed through an internal "rate-matching" hub (RMH) and **the EHCI controller indirectly provides full and low speed USB functions**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)

You can take a look at the specification on Intel's web site:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/ehci-specification-for-usb.html

Comment: I would remove the word "devices" from your first sentence, and say "hosts".  It is much more clear.  Especially because there are many USB 2.0 devices that do not support the full range of speeds; some USB 2.0 devices offer only Full Speed or Low Speed, some offer only High Speed or Full Speed.  Also, some hosts will offer Full and Low speed compatibility with companion controllers, although USB 3.0 is changing that.